# Marker(Mapbox) React typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mapbox-gl-js

I would like to add id to Marker(), but it's showing the error Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Marker'.

There is a way how to add an id to non-existent property??

Here is my code....

```
const maps = useRef<mapboxgl.Map | null>(null);

const markers = useRef<any>({}); // for the moment is any


useEffect(() => {
    maps.current?.on('click', (ev: mapboxgl.MapMouseEvent & mapboxgl.EventData) => {
      const { lng, lat } = ev.lngLat;

      const marker = new mapboxgl.Marker();
      marker.id = uuidV4(); // id' does not exist on type 'Marker

      marker.setLngLat([lng, lat]).addTo(maps.current!).setDraggable(true);

      markers.current[marker.id] = marker; // id' does not exist on type 'Marker
    });
  }, []);
```

I am new to typescript so, I'll be happy to get a tips and solution.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own type that extends the mapbox marker type and adds an `id` property.

```
type MarkerWithId = mapboxgl.Marker & {id: string}
```

Your `markers` ref is a dictionary of these objects.

```
const markers = useRef<Record<string, MarkerWithId>>({});
```

When you call `new mapboxgl.Marker()` you get a marker without an `id`, so you need to use a type assertion.

```
const marker = new mapboxgl.Marker() as MarkerWithId;
```

The rest should be fine!

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works everything without error.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set it on the `getElement()` method which returns the DOM element to use as a marker. The default is a light blue, droplet-shaped SVG marker.

```js
 marker.getElement().id = uuidV4();

 marker.setLngLat([lng, lat]).addTo(map.current!).setDraggable(true);
 
 markers.current[marker.getElement().id] = marker;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is good to know another kind of solution. Happy to learn from you.